# how to calculate time used in one activity on eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, phpmyadmin

I'm doing android application project. I want to record the time used on each activity in my application and save each time used in phpmyadmin database. For example, if the consumer clicks the button on for the first activity, my application will go to first activity. I want my application to record time used from the start first activity and will stop if user click the button. I will hope , ypu can help me to settle this problem.. :)

Comment: Please post you tried code or problem at here.

Answer (score 3):

In each activity, have a member variable like this:

```
private long mStartTime;
```

In your onResume/onCreate method in each activity, add this:

```
mStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

In your onPause/onStop method in each activity, add this:

```
long timeSpentInThisActivityMillisec = System.currentTimeMillis() - mStartTime;
// send time to phpmyadmin database
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you very much sir.. Now, i already know how much time user spend time with my application. But, i don't know how to send the total time spend to phpmyadmin database. Hope, you can help me. thank you. :)

Comment: Your question was *"how to calculate time used in one activity"*, so I assumed you already know how to use phpmyadmin. I'm afraid I don't know anything about that.

Comment: thank you sir.i have done calculate time used in one activity. And now, i successfully store time used in phpmyadmin...thank very much for your helping.. :)